# OutOfMemory exception in WinForms RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, out-of-memory

I'm using `RichTextBox` instances in few methods which are changing font, color, converting images to Rtf format.

```
public static string ColorText(string text)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

    rtb.Text = conversation;

    // find predefined keywords in text, select them and color them

    return rtb.Rtf;
}
```

After a while I'm getting `OutOfMemory` Exception. Should I call `rtb.Dispose();`? Or `GC.Collect` or use `using` Or whats the right way?

Comment: Are you sure the `RichTextBox` is giving you the out of memory exception? Can you share the exception?

Comment: this doesn't make sense except you have a infinite loop somewhere

Comment: The exception is shown after a few hours of use. I think that something is kept in memory. But I don't know why. I tried use Dispose, using and GC. And now waiting that it will do in Process Monitor.

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), specifically the part about code examples. Also, it is difficult to help unless you can post either the exception stack trace, or steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm sorry and thanks for link I'll make my questions better. That is the primary point of my question is that if when I've a few windows with RichTextBoxs and a lot of formatted text in it and it all in one app. And I'll close some windows if it will Dispose resources of RTB automatically of I shoud call GC.Collect. And if I use RTB instance in method if I should use using or Dispose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell from the debugger, the rtb.IsHandleCreated property will be *true* after you obtain the Rtf property value.  That's a problem, window handles keep their wrapper control alive.  You *must* dispose the control again to destroy the handle:

```
public static string ColorText(string text) {
    using (var rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()) {
        rtb.Text = text;
        return rtb.Rtf;
    }
}
```

Or store "rtb" in a static variable so you only ever use one instance.